# An alternative way to compute $a^n+b^n+c^n+d^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I was doing the following problem:

given $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}$ and

$a+b+c+d=1$, $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=2$, $a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3=3$ and $a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4=4$.

Find $a^n+b^n+c^n+d^n$ (I am looking for a closed kind of formula)

Now, I can already do it in one way. We can find the elementary symmetric polynomials using newton's identity and then solve the quartic to find the values of $a, b, c, d$.

But I realise that my method is computationally heavy. And more importantly once the number of variables is increased there is no guarantee that we can solve for the roots. Also, the problem does not really need the values of $a, b, c, d$ explicitly.

The above observations motivate me to find an alternative way to find a  an alternative technique to solve problems like this(may be in a more general setting).

So,  can someone help me?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1661035/prove-fraca3b3c33-fraca7b7c77-left-fraca5b5c55

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, the techniques in the links do not show any method to find an explicit formula for $a^n+b^n+c^n+d^n$. Sorr, for not explicitly mentioning that. They just use newton identities to recursively find the values. I am aware for that method. BTW, thanks for the links.

Comment: An intuitive guess is $n$

Comment: Note that $(a(a-1))^2+(b(b-1))^2+(c(c-1))^2+(d(d-1))^2=0$. But they are not real numbers.

Answer (score 3):

If we take $a,b,c,d$ as the roots of a monic polynomial
$$ p(x)=x^4-e_1 x^3+e_2 x^2-e_3 x+e_4 $$
[Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_identities) give:
$$ \left\{\begin{array}{rcl}e_1 &=& 1\\ 2e_2 &=& e_1-2 \\ 3e_3 &=& e_2 - 2e_1 +3 \\ 4e_4 &=& e_3-2e_2+3e_1-4  \end{array}\right. $$
hence it follows that:
$$ e_1=1,\quad e_2 = -\frac{1}{2},\quad e_3 = \frac{1}{6},\quad e_4 = \frac{1}{24}, $$
$$ p(x) = x^4-x^3-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x}{6}+\frac{1}{24} $$
and:

> $$ a^n+b^n+c^n+d^n = \text{Tr}\,\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{24} \\ 
> 1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}^n .$$

Since the dominant root of $p(x)$ is about $1.42016$ and the other ones are quite close to zero, $a^n+b^n+c^n+d^n$ almost behaves like $2^{n/2}$ for large $n$s.

Comment: Thanks. Sir, can you take a look at this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1671738/explaining-newton-polygon-in-elementary-way