# How we can show this ;$\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{2}\times\frac{x^5+y^5+z^5}{5}=\frac{x^7+y^7+z^7}{7}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Let be $\quad x+y+z=0$

show this:

$$\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{2}\times\frac{x^5+y^5+z^5}{5}=\frac{x^7+y^7+z^7}{7}$$

I solved ,but Im interesting what are you thinking about this,how can we arrive to solution quickly?

Comment: I'm almost sure this is a duplicate

Comment: This one is not exactly the same, but similar: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851985/big-dfracx7y7z77-big2-big-dfracx5y5z55-big2-cdot-big

Comment: @mercio and Hans Lundmark thank you,

I am like that found.

$3(x^{2n+1}+y^{2n+1}+z^{2n+1})=(-1)^{n+1}.(2n+1)(x.y.z)[x^{n-1}.y^{n-1}+x^{n-1}.z^{n-1}+y^{n-1}.z^{n-1}]$

Comment: "Show this" or "solve this"? those are different questions.  I'm not sure that equation is always true so I think you mean "solve this".

Comment: for $x+y+z=0$ ,
$x+y=-z$,
$x+z=-y$,
$y+z=-x$,

$(x+y)^3=-z^3=x^3+y^3+3xy(x+y)$
,
$x^3+y^3+z^3=3xyz$
,
and $x^5+y^5+z^5=-5x^2y^2z$ 
,
$\vdots$
$\vdots$

$n\in\mathbb{N^{+}}$
.......................................................
for $x+y=-z$
,
$x^{2n+1}+y^{2n+1}+z^{2n+1}=(-1)^{n+1}.(2n+1)(x^n.y^n.z)$
...........................................
for $x+z=-y$
,
$x^{2n+1}n+y^{2n+1}+z^{2n+1}=(-1)^{n+1}.(2n+1)(x^n.y.z^n)$

............................................
for $y+z=-x$ 
,
$x^{2n+1}+y^{2n+1}+z^{2n+1}=(-1)^{n+1}.(2n+1)(x.y^n.z^n)$

Comment: and let's make a together form;

$\forall x,y,z$    :   $x+y+z=0$  

$3(x^{2n+1}+y^{2n+1}+z^{2n+1})=(-1)^{n+1}.(2n+1)[x^n.y^n.z+x^n.y.z^n+x.y^n.z^n]$

and

$3(x^{2n+1}+y^{2n+1}+z^{2n+1})=(-1)^{n+1}.(2n+1)(x.y.z)[x^{n-1}.y^{n-1}+x^{n-1}.z^{n-1}+y^{n-1}.z^{n-1}]$ $\quad\Box$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your polynomials are invariant by the action of $S_3$ on $(x,y,z)$.

A standard result says that the graded ring $\Bbb Q[x,y,z]^{S_3}$ is $\Bbb Q[x+y+z;xy+yz+xz;xyz]$.

Furthermore here, quotienting by $(x+y+z)$ we can work in the ring $(\Bbb Q[x,y,z]/(x+y+z))^{S_3} \cong \Bbb Q[xy+yz+xz;xyz]$.

Now in this graded ring, the pieces of degree $2,5,7$ are all of dimension $1$ (there is only one decomposition of $2,5,7$ as a sum of $2$s and $3$s).

Picking $x,y,z = 1,1,-2$ shows that $x^k+y^k+z^k$ are nonzero in that ring for $k > 1$, which proves that $(x^2+y^2+z^2)(x^5+y^5+z^5) = q (x^7+y^7+z^7) \pmod {x+y+z}$ for a rational number $q$ (and also that $(x^2+y^2+z^2)(x^3+y^3+z^3) = q' (x^5+y^5+z^5)$ but we don't particularly care).

Then you can easily check that when replacing $z$ with $-x-y$ in your expressions, the dominant coefficient in your polynomials is $1$ after doing the
divisions (note that for an odd prime $p$, by Fermat's little theorem, $(x^p+y^p+(-x-y)^p)/p$ even has integral coefficients, ... and the case $p=2$ just works), and you only have to check $1 \times 1 = 1$ to finish the proof.

You can also evaluate $(x^2+y^2+z^2)(x^5+y^5+z^5) = q (x^7+y^7+z^7)$ at $x,y,z = 1,1,-2$ to get $6\times (-30) = q \times (-126)$ hence $q=10/7$.