# Generalizing $ \frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{2} \times \frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{3} = \frac{a^5+b^5+c^5}{5}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

If $a+b+c=0$ as discussed in [*this*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2469296/if-abc-0-prove-that-fraca2b2c22-times-fraca3b3c33), [*this*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1812706/how-we-can-show-this-fracx2y2z22-times-fracx5y5z55-fracx), and [*this*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2747626/suppose-xyz-0-show-that-fracx5y5z55-fracx2y2z22-tim) post, then,

$$ \frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{2} \times \frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{3} = \frac{a^5+b^5+c^5}{5}\tag1 $$
$$ \frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{3} \times \frac{a^4+b^4+c^4}{2} = \frac{a^7+b^7+c^7}{7}\tag2 $$
$$ \frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{2} \times \frac{a^5+b^5+c^5}{5} = \frac{a^7+b^7+c^7}{7}\tag3 $$
Using these basic identities, we can prove the nice squared identities [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1661035/prove-fraca3b3c33-fraca7b7c77-left-fraca5b5c55), 
$$ \frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{3}\times \frac{a^7+b^7+c^7}{7} = \left(\frac{a^5+b^5+c^5}{5}\right)^2 $$

and [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851985/) for $(a^7+b^7+c^7)^2$. Some investigation shows that,

$$\frac{(a^5+b^5+c^5)}{5\times18}\times\big(9(a^6+b^6+c^6) -(a^3+b^3+c^3)^2\big)=  \frac{a^{11}+b^{11}+c^{11}}{11}\tag4$$
$$\frac{(a^7+b^7+c^7)}{7\times18}\times\big(9(a^6+b^6+c^6) +(a^3+b^3+c^3)^2\big)=  \frac{a^{13}+b^{13}+c^{13}}{13}\tag5$$

> **Q:** What would be the corresponding identities, as concise as possible, for $p=17$ and $p=19$?

Comment: Use grobner basis in SAGE, for instance.

Comment: @RafaelGonzalezLopez: As $(2)$ and $(3)$ shows, there may be several ways to do it. A concise and elegant form would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When denote 
$$
s_k = \dfrac{a^k+b^k+c^k}{k},
$$

then some expressions for $s_{17}$ and $s_{19}$:

$$
s_5 \left(6s_{12}-7s_5s_7-\frac{1}{2}{s_3^4}\right) = s_{17},
$$

$$
s_7 \left(6s_{12}-5s_5s_7+\frac{3}{2}{s_3^4}\right) = s_{19}.
$$

Or
$$
s_5 \left(s_{12}+3s_6^2+4s_4s_8\right) = s_{17},
$$

$$
s_7 \left(3s_{12}+9s_6^2-4s_4s_8\right) = s_{19}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the similarity to the ones for $p=11,\,13$.

Answer (score 2):

Define $\;s_k := (a^k+b^k+c^k)/k.\;$ Then
 $\;s_{17}=2s_{13}s_4+3s_9s_5s_3,\; s_{19}=8s_8s_7s_4+3s_{11}s_5s_3.$

Not as nice as the ones for $\;s_{11}\;$ and $\;s_{13}\;$ but they are two terms with positive integer coefficients.

Comment: Nice answer (+). As for $s_{19}$: there is a bit shorter expression for $s_{19}$: $$s_{19} = s_2s_{17}+2s_{3}s_{5}s_{11};$$ but it uses $s_{17}$, don't know if it is allowed.