# Ordered pairs $(m,n)$ such that ${\frac{a^{m+n}+b^{m+n}+c^{m+n}}{m+n}=\frac{(a^m+b^m+c^m)}{m}\frac{(a^n+b^n+c^n)}{n}}$.

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

I am unable to proceed with the following problem, : If $a+b+c=0$ then find all the ordered pairs $(m,n)$ where $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$\boxed{\frac{a^{m+n}+b^{m+n}+c^{m+n}}{m+n}=\frac{(a^m+b^m+c^m)}{m}\frac{(a^n+b^n+c^n)}{n}}$$

I tried but I think I have no idea regarding this kind of problem although I tried a bit hard with all possible methods (which I can do/know) but that doesn't result any substantial thing which I can add and also it will not give a complete set of solutions, this trial approach provides a few solution(and quite laborious and too many limitations) for instance this well known stuff if $a+b+c=0$ then, $\frac{a^5+b^5+c^5}{5}=(\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{3})(\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{2})$ is one of the solution. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Inquisitive you are, be a little attemptive  as well! Can you think of obvious pairs which work? Which don't work? Take examples : for example take $a = -b$ and $c=0$ to simplify things, then what works?

Comment: @teresa but it will not give a complete set of solutions, this trial approach provides a few solution(and quite laborious and too many limitations) for instance this well known stuff if $a+b+c=0$ then $\frac{a^5+b^5+c^5}{5}=\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{3}\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{2}$ For your concern! yeah, I have done that but it was not quite good anyway $\cdots$

Comment: What is your source for this problem? Also look up symmetric polynomials, the Newton-Girard formula as well, they seem related.

Comment: @ teresa but I can't proceed and connect the stuffs, can you help a bit more?

Comment: That is fine, I want to know the source for your problem.

Comment: @teresa have you heard the name of the book pre collage mathematics

Comment: Oh, its from that book (The challenge and thrill of pre-college mathematics)? Great book that one, and yes, then this is a nice question for sure.

Comment: Here's something I tried : I put $a=-2,b=1,c=1$ and ran a program, generated a table and looked up when the products matched. It seems that only $(2,3),(3,2),(2,5),(5,2)$ work. That proves that these are necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us first consider the case $m\le n$.

- If $m=n$, then taking $(a,b,c)=(1,-1,0)$, we get $m=(1+(-1)^m)^2$ from which $m=4$ follows. However, when $m=n=4$, the equation does not hold for $(a,b,c)=(2,-1,-1)$.
- If $m=1$, then taking $(a,b,c)=(2,-1,-1)$, we get $2^{n}=(-1)^{n}$ which is impossible.

So, in the following, $2\le m\lt n$.

- If both $m$ and $n$ are odd, then taking $(a,b,c)=(2,-1,-1)$, we get
  $$mn(2^{m+n-1}+1)=2(m+n)(2^{m-1}+(-1)^m)(2^{n-1}+(-1)^n)$$The LHS is odd while the RHS is even, which is impossible.
- If both $m$ and $n$ are even, then taking $(a,b,c)=(1,-1,0)$, we get $(m-2)(n-2)=4$, but there are no solutions satisfying $2\le m\lt n$.
- If exactly one of $m,n$ is odd, then taking $(a,b,c)=(2,-1,-1)$, we get
  $$mn(2^{m+n}-2)=(m+n)(2^m+2(-1)^m)(2^n+2(-1)^n)\tag1$$Suppose here that $m$ is odd. Then, since we have $mn\gt m+n\ (\gt 0)$ (which is equivalent to $(m-1)(n-1)\gt 1$ which is true) and $$2^{m+n}-2\gt (2^m+2(-1)^m)(2^n+2(-1)^n)\ \ (\gt 0)$$ (which is equivalent to $2\gt 2^{m+1}-2^{n+1}$ which is true), the LHS of $(1)$ is larger than the RHS of $(1)$. So, $m$ has to be even to have
  $$2^n\bigg(\underbrace{n(m2^{m}-2^{m}-2)-2^mm-2m}_{A}\bigg)+\underbrace{n(2^{m+1}-2m+4)+4m(2^{m-1}+1)}_{\gt 0}=0\tag2$$Now, suppose that $m\ge 4$. Then, we have
  $$\begin{align}A=n\underbrace{(m2^{m}-2^{m}-2)}_{\gt 0}-2^mm-2m&\gt m(m2^{m}-2^{m}-2)-2^mm-2m
  \\&=4m\bigg((m-2)2^{m-2}-1\bigg)
  \\\\&\gt 0\end{align}$$implying that the LHS of $(2)$ is positive. So, we have to have $m=2$. Taking $(a,b,c)=(2,-1,-1)$, we have$$(n-6)2^{n-1}+2n+6=0\tag3$$Suppose here that $n\ge 7$. Then, the LHS of $(3)$ is positive. So, we get $n=3,5$ which are sufficient (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2469296/if-abc-0-prove-that-fraca2b2c22-times-fraca3b3c33), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1812706/how-we-can-show-this-fracx2y2z22-times-fracx5y5z55-fracx), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2747626/suppose-xyz-0-show-that-fracx5y5z55-fracx2y2z22-tim)).

In conclusion, considering the case $m\gt  n$, we see that the answer is
$$\color{red}{(m,n)=(2,3),(3,2),(2,5),(5,2)}$$

Comment: Excellent answer !! (+1)