# For $a, b, c$ with $a+b+c=0$ prove $\frac15\sum a^5=\frac13\sum a^3\cdot\frac12\sum a^2$ and $\frac17\sum a^7=\frac15\sum a^5\cdot\frac12\sum a^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math

Consider the following problem:

> **Problem.** Suppose that real numbers $a$, $b$ and $c$ satisfy the condition $a+b+c=0$. Prove the following identities:
> $$
> \frac{a^5+b^5+c^5}{5}=\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{3}\cdot\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{2},
> \\
> \frac{a^7+b^7+c^7}{7}=\frac{a^5+b^5+c^5}{5}\cdot\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{2}.
> $$

Perhaps, the shortest solution I can think of is as follows: plug $c=-a-b$ into the equation but instead of expanding everything use the following identities
$$
(a+b)^3-a^3-b^3=3ab(a+b),
\\
(a+b)^5-a^5-b^5=5ab(a+b)(a^2+ab+b^2),
\\
(a+b)^7-a^7-b^7=7ab(a+b)(a^2+ab+b^2)^2.
$$
However, these identies are coming out of nowhere and moreover, in order to prove them one still needs to do some computations.

> **Question.** Is it possible to solve this problem in a "smart" way (i.e. avoiding computations and preferrably elementary since it is almost a high school problem)? Any other solutions are also welcome.

**Comment.** It should be also noted that it is unclear (at least for me) how those identies were invented. It seems there is no nice similar identities for $\frac{a^p+b^p+c^p}{p}$ for $p$ other than 2, 3, 5, 7.

Comment: Use [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) with $e_1=0$.

Comment: Related: [Ordered pairs $(m,n)$ such that ${\frac{a^{m+n}+b^{m+n}+c^{m+n}}{m+n}=\frac{(a^m+b^m+c^m)}{m}\frac{(a^n+b^n+c^n)}{n}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3972109/ordered-pairs-m-n-such-that-fracamnbmncmnmn-fracam).

Comment: @user376343 Indeed, but it wasn't me who changed the title. I'll try to fix it.

Comment: @richrow: Whoops! Sorry about the bad title. A bit of mis-reading *and* mis-typing on my part. I need a nap. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem about elementary symmetric functions. Let
$$s_1=a=b+c$$
$$s_2=ab+bc+ac$$
$$s_3=abc$$

Now assuming that $s_1=a+b+c=0$ we show that

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
-\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{2}&=s_2=ab+bc+ca\\
\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{3}&=s_3=abc\\
-\frac{a^4+b^4+c^4}{4}&=-\frac{1}{2}s_2^2=-\frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2}{2}\\
\frac{a^5+b^5+c^5}{5}&=-s_2s_3\\
-\frac{a^6+b^6+c^6}{6}&=-\frac{1}{2}s_3^2+\frac{1}{3}s_2^3\\
-\frac{a^7+b^7+c^7}{7}&=s_2^2s_3\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

And the results follow.

The calculational scheme for deriving the above equalities is

to note that

$$\ln (1+ax)=ax-\frac{a^2}{2}x^2+\frac{a^3}{3}x^3+\cdots $$
and adding,

$$\ln (1+ax)(1+bx)(1+cx)=
(a+b+c)x-\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{2}x^2+
\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{3}x^3+\cdots $$

on the other hand,

$$(1+ax)(1+bx)(1+cx)= 1+s_1x+s_2x^2+s_3x^3$$
so we have under the assumption that $s_1=0$,

$$\ln (1+s_2x^2+s_3x^3)=(s_2x^2+s_3x^3)-\frac{1}{2}
(s_2x^2+s_3x^3)^2+\frac{1}{3}(s_2x^2+s_3x^3)^3\cdots $$
from which the above equalities follow easily by equating the coefficients of the two power series.

In particular this shows that every $\frac{a^n+b^n+c^n}{n}$ is a polynomial in $n=2,3$ assuming $s_1=0$.

Answer (score 2):

let's have a look at the following identities called Lame-type identities (see [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/001a&ved=2ahUKEwj2juXErp_yAhWVDWMBHVmvDNYQFnoECAQQAg&usg=AOvVaw1R4_XQGPWxibcETPH1t8Gg&cshid=1628357102878)).

$$(x+y+z)^3 - (x^3+y^3+z^3) = 3(x+y)(x+z)(y+z)$$

$$(x+y+z)^5 - (x^5+y^5+z^5) = 5(x+y)(x+z)(y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2+xy+xz+yz)$$

$$(x+y+z)^7 - (x^7+y^7+z^7) = 7(x+y)(x+z)(y+z)((x^2+y^2+z^2+xy+xz+yz)^2+xyz(x+y+z))$$

Algebraically manipulating the second and third identities give;

Let
$$A = x+y+z,$$
$$B = x^2+y^2+z^2,$$
$$C = x^3+y^3+z^3,$$
$$E = x^5+y^5+z^5,$$
$$G = x^7+y^7+z^7,$$
then
\begin{equation}
6E=A^5-5BA^3+5CA^2+5BC \tag{1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
36G=A^7+7CA^4-21B^2A^3+28C^2A+21B^2C \tag{2}
\end{equation}

So, letting $A=0$ reduces (1) and (2) to the original problems.
Hope that solves the problems.

> I have found, using computer, that an identity for the 9th powers is:
> \begin{align}
> 72\frac{(x^9+y^9+z^9)}{(x^3+y^3+z^3)}=&27(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2 +8(x^3+y^3+z^3)^2
> \end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way:

Let $a,b,c$ be the roots of the cubic equation $$x^3+px+q=0$$
(The $x^2$ coefficient is zero since $\sum a=0$)

Then $$\sum a^2=(\sum a)^2-2\sum ab=-2p$$
$$\sum a^3=-p\sum a-q\sum 1=-3q$$
$$\sum a^4=-p\sum a^2-q\sum a=2p^2$$
$$\sum a^5=-p\sum a^3-q\sum a^2=5pq$$
Therefore $$pq=\frac15\sum a^5=\frac13\sum a^3\cdot\frac12\sum a^2$$
Also,
$$\sum a^7=-p\sum a^5-q\sum a^4=-7p^2q$$
$$\implies-p^2q=\frac17\sum a^7=(pq)(-p)=\frac15\sum a^5\cdot\frac12\sum a^2$$

Answer (score 1):

I'll tackle the first identity. The idea is to use Newton's sums. Note that $P_2=a^2+b^2+c^2=S_1P_1-2S_2=-2S_2$.
Additionally, $P_3=S_1P_2-S_2P_1+3S_3=3S_3$. Also,
$$P_5=S_1P_4-S_2P_3+S_3P_2-S_4P_1+5S_5=S_3P_2-S_2P_3+5S_5$$
So we want to prove
$$-S_2S_3=S_5+\frac{1}{5}(S_3P_2-S_2P_3)$$
$$-(ab+bc+ac)(abc)=\frac{1}{5}(-2abc(ab+bc+ac)-3abc(ab+bc+ac))$$
Since $S_5=0$. This is clearly true, as desired. The second can be solved similarly, but might require a bit more work.