# show that amazing result $\frac{\sum a^7}{\sum a^5\sum a^2}=\frac{7}{10}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, symmetric-polynomials

Let $a,b,c,d,e,f$ be real numbers,such $a+b+c+d+e+f=a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3+e^3+f^3=0$ show that 
$$\dfrac{a^7+b^7+c^7+d^7+e^7+f^7}{(a^5+b^5+c^5+d^5+e^5+f^5)(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+e^2+f^2)}=\dfrac{7}{10}$$
or

if we let $S_{i}=a^i+b^i+c^i+d^i+e^i+f^i$,and such
$$S_{1}=S_{3}=0$$
then we 
$$\dfrac{S_{7}}{S_{5}S_{2}}=\dfrac{7}{10}$$I read about it in a book, and it felt amazing, and I tried for a long time, and I didn't prove it.

Comment: Is there anything special about the fact that you have _six_ numbers? Does the same (possibly with a different value than $\frac{7}{10}$) hold for just $a,b,c$, for instance? Or do you have to use $\frac{S_4}{S_2S_2}$ instead? Or does it just not work? These are the kinds of things you ought to explore if you want to try finding a solution on your own. You can't just stare at it and hope that the answer pops into your head.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851985/big-dfracx7y7z77-big2-big-dfracx5y5z55-big2-cdot-big

Comment: @labbhattacharjee,but my problem are six numbers,so maybe it's ugly than three numbers

Comment: This might be not the shortest way to solve this, but $$x^n+y^n=(x+y)(x^{n-1}+y^{n-1})-xy(x^{n-2}+y^{n-2})$$$$x^n+y^n+z^n=(x+y+z)(x^{n-1}+y^{n-1}+z^{n-1})-(xy+yz+zx)(x^{n-2}+y^{n-2}+z^{n-2})+xyz(x^{n-3}+y^{n-3}+z^{n-3})$$ and so on. Then you can use [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) to expand your power sum and evaluate each [symmetric polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial) of 6 variables using the given details.

Comment: This is better stated in the form of Karn Watcharasupat's answer, because it's possible that the sum of the fifth powers is $0$ also, as when $a=b=c=1,\space d=e=f=-1$

Comment: @Arthur Lol I always fall for that trap... I have of course seen this advice before, but  for some reason I always forget to use it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Note: The original, more step-by-step approach is below the line.
>
> Notations used in this answer:
>   \begin{align}
> S_r&=\sum_{1\le i \le 6}{x_i^r}\\
> e_r&=\displaystyle{\sum_{{{1\le \underbrace{i\le j \le k \le \ldots}_{\displaystyle{{r \text{ indices}}}}} \le 6}}}\underbrace{x_ix_jx_k\cdots x_{\dots}}_{r \text{ factors}}\\
> e_1&=x_1+\dots+x_6\\
> e_2&=x_1x_2+x_1x_3+\dots+x_2x_3+\dots+x_5x_6\\
> e_6&=x_1x_2\cdots x_6\\
> \left(e_r\right)_{r>6}&=0
> \end{align}
>   Identities: refer to [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities)

\end{align}
**The 'one-shot' proof:**
\begin{align}
  & \frac{{{S}_{7}}}{{{S}_{2}}{{S}_{5}}}=\frac{\overbrace{{{e}_{1}}}^{={{S}_{1}}=0}{{S}_{6}}-{{e}_{2}}{{S}_{5}}+{{e}_{3}}{{S}_{4}}-{{e}_{4}}\overbrace{{{S}_{3}}}^{=0}+{{e}_{5}}{{S}_{2}}-{{e}_{6}}\overbrace{{{S}_{1}}}^{=0}+7\overbrace{{{e}_{7}}}^{=0}}{\left( \underbrace{{{e}_{1}}}_{=0}\underbrace{{{S}_{1}}}_{=0}-2{{e}_{2}} \right)\left( \underbrace{{{e}_{1}}}_{=0}{{S}_{4}}-{{e}_{2}}\underbrace{{{S}_{3}}}_{=0}+{{e}_{3}}{{S}_{2}}-{{e}_{4}}\underbrace{{{S}_{1}}}_{=0}+5{{e}_{5}} \right)} \\ 
 & =\frac{-{{e}_{2}}{{S}_{5}}+{{e}_{3}}{{S}_{4}}+{{e}_{5}}{{S}_{2}}}{\left( -2{{e}_{2}} \right)\left( {{e}_{3}}{{S}_{2}}+5{{e}_{5}} \right)} \\ 
 & =\frac{-{{e}_{2}}{{S}_{5}}+0\cdot {{S}_{4}}+{{e}_{5}}{{S}_{2}}}{\left( -2{{e}_{2}} \right)\left( 0\cdot {{S}_{2}}+5{{e}_{5}} \right)}\qquad\qquad\qquad\because 3{{e}_{2}}={{e}_{2}}\underbrace{{{S}_{1}}}_{=0}-\underbrace{{{e}_{1}}}_{=0}{{S}_{2}}+\underbrace{{{S}_{3}}}_{=0}=0 \\ 
 & =\frac{-{{e}_{2}}{{S}_{5}}+{{e}_{5}}{{S}_{2}}}{\left( -2{{e}_{2}} \right)\left( 5{{e}_{5}} \right)} \\ 
 & =\frac{-\frac{1}{2}\left( {{e}_{1}}{{S}_{1}}-{{S}_{2}} \right){{S}_{5}}+{{e}_{5}}{{S}_{2}}}{\left( -2\left( {{e}_{1}}{{S}_{1}}-{{S}_{2}} \right) \right)\left( 5{{e}_{5}} \right)}\qquad\qquad\qquad\because 2{{e}_{2}}=\underbrace{{{e}_{1}}{{S}_{1}}}_{=0}-{{S}_{2}}\Rightarrow {{S}_{2}}=-\frac{1}{2}{{e}_{2}} \\ 
 & =\frac{\frac{1}{2}{{S}_{2}}{{S}_{5}}+{{e}_{5}}{{S}_{2}}}{5{{e}_{5}}{{S}_{2}}} \\ 
 & =\frac{{{S}_{5}}+2{{e}_{5}}}{10{{e}_{5}}}\qquad\qquad\because 5{{e}_{5}}={{e}_{4}}\underbrace{{{S}_{1}}}_{=0}-\underbrace{{{e}_{3}}}_{=0}{{S}_{2}}+{{e}_{2}}\underbrace{{{S}_{3}}}_{=0}-\underbrace{{{e}_{1}}}_{=0}{{S}_{4}}+{{S}_{5}}\Rightarrow {{S}_{5}}=5{{e}_{5}} \\ 
 & =\frac{5{{e}_{5}}+2{{e}_{5}}}{10{{e}_{5}}} \\ 
 & =\frac{7}{10}  
\end{align}

---

Consider
\begin{align}
\sum_{1\le i\le6}{x^2_i}
&=\left(\sum_{1\le i\le6}{x_i}\right)^2
-2(\underbrace{x_1x_2+x_2x_3+\ldots+x_5x_6}_\text{all permuations of pairs})\\
&=0-2(\underbrace{x_1x_2+x_2x_3+\ldots+x_5x_6}_\text{all permuations of pairs})\\
\frac12S_2&=-\sum_{1\le i\le j \le6}{x_ix_j}=-e_2
\end{align}

Using [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) (which you can sort of observe yourself also)
\begin{align}
S_5
&=\underbrace{\left(\sum_{1\le i\le6}{x_i}\right)}_{=0}S_4
-\left(\overbrace{\sum_{1\le i\le j\le6}{x_ix_j}}^{e_2}\right)\underbrace{S_3}_{=0}
+\left(\overbrace{\sum_{1\le i\le j\le k \le6}{x_ix_jx_k}}^{e_3}\right)S_2
-\left(\overbrace{\sum_{1\le i\le j\le k \le k \le 6}{x_ix_jx_kx_l}}^{e_4}\right)\underbrace{S_1}_{=0}+e_5\\
&=0-0+e_3S_2-0\\
&=e_3S_2+5e_5
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
S_7
&=\underbrace{e_1}_{=S_1=0}S_6
-e_2S_5
+e_3S_4
-e_4S_3
+e_5S_2-e_6S_1+7\underbrace{e_7}_{=0}\\
&=-e_2S_5
+e_3S_4
+e_5S_2\\
\end{align}

Then we settle some unfinished business with our dear $e_3$,
\begin{align}
S_3&=e_1S_2-e_2S_1+3e_3\\
0&=0-0+3e_3\\
e_3&=0
\end{align}
so we have
\begin{align}
S_5&=e_3S_2+5e_5\\
S_5&=0+5e_5\\
e_5&=\frac{1}{5}S_5
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
S_7
&=-e_2S_5+e_3S_4+e_5S_2\\
&=\frac12S_2S_5+0+\frac15S_2S_5\\
&=\frac7{10}S_2S_5
\end{align}

Comment: Hello,this identity How prove it?

Comment: How about a little more of a hint?

Comment: @saulspatz I hope it's clearer now

Comment: if use this it's ugly,even can't work it,because $\sum_{1\le i\le 7}x^5_{i}=\sum_{i=1}^{7}x^2_{i}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{7}x^3_{i}-\cdots$,and $\cdots$ is ugly form,so I can't it

Comment: @functionsug see the newest edit. Is it better now?

Comment: @KarnWatcharasupat,Thanks, and How to determine $\sum_{ijk}x_{i}x_{j}x_{k}$?,and if we determine the $\sum_{i=1}^{7}x^7_{i}$ maybe $\sum_{ijklm}x_{i}x_{j}x_{k}x_{l}x_{m}$ and so on,then we how to determine this?

Comment: because $\sum_{i=1}^{7}x^7_{i}=-\sum_{ij}x_{i}x_{j}\sum_{i}x^5_{i}+\sum_{ijk}x_{i}x_{j}x_{k}\sum_{i}x^4_{i}+\sum_{ijklm}x_{i}x_{j}x_{k}x_{l}x_{m}\sum_{i}x^2_{i}$

Comment: Now how to determin this $\sum_{ijklmn}x_{i}x_{j}x_{l}x_{k}x_{m}\sum_{i}x^2_{i}?$,Thanks

Comment: @KarnWatcharasupat Much clearer, thanks.  +1

Comment: @functionsug the complete proof is here. I wasted a lot of time searching for a careless mistake.