# Showing $\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{2}\cdot\frac{x^5+y^5+z^5}{5}=\frac{x^7+y^7+z^7}{7}$ when $x+y+z=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

> If $x+y+z=0$ prove that $$\left(\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{2}\right)\cdot \left(\frac{x^5+y^5+z^5}{5}\right)=\frac{x^7+y^7+z^7}{7}$$

My work: After doing some calculation, I came on the conclusion that if the above statement is true then this statement $$\frac{x^2(y^5+z^5)+y^2(x^5+z^5)+z^2(y^5+x^5)}{x^7+y^7+z^7}=\frac37$$ must also be true.

Aftet this I'm stuck. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @DietrichBurde you really nailed it bro but can you pls give a full expansion

Comment: I'm having some problems in determining the denominator

Comment: See [quora](https://www.quora.com/If-x+y+z-0-how-do-you-prove-that-x-2+y-2+z-2-2-x-5+y-5+z-5-5-x-7+y-7+z-7-7) for a solution.

Comment: Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/851985/977780

Comment: @NobodyNobody Please search on  MSE before posting. You could find similar questions and even you could find the same question that you are going to ask.